# Random problems with connection to MySQL from Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have application, which connects to MySQL database. Everything is fine when app runs on Windows Server 2016, but lastly I migrated it to Azure App Service as continous Web Job and I get completely randomly errors:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<ExecuteImplAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()``
```

I try to create connection every time when my app retrieves message from queue.
I use `Dapper` and piece of my code, which connects to MySQL looks like this:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    return await connection.QueryAsync<Resource>(this._getContactsToSync);
}
```

MySQL version is 5.5 - quite old, but it's customer external source and I can't do anything with that.
I tested three versions of MySQL drivers for .NET (8.0, 6.9, 6.10) - error occurs with every of them.

I found somewhere information, that this situation could be caused by to many open sockets, but I tested app locally with `netstat` command and everything looks good.

My issue is similar to this:
[Random connection problems from Azure C# app to remote MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906526/random-connection-problems-from-azure-c-sharp-app-to-remote-mysql-server), but there is'nt any helpful answer.

I've never done anything with MySQL, so I'm not an expert with this tool. Maybe someone has similar situation???

Comment: Try to add your IP to whitelist in hosting admin panel

Comment: I added every outbound IP address from Azure Web App to whitelist in MySQL. I investigated logs from Azure in Wireshark and I noticed that in situation when error occurs there is a problem with creating new TCP connection. It looks like my request sometimes doesn't go out from Azure (???)

Comment: Try removing 'port' in connection string

Comment: I don't have port in connection string: `Server=123.123.123.123; Database=xxxxx; Uid=xxxxx; Pwd=xxxxxx; Convert Zero Datetime=True;maximumpoolsize=20;Connection Timeout=10;`

Comment: Maybe one of the fixes in this thread could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I noticed today that when I use _tcpping_ on MySQL port in Azure Kudu console I receive timeouts from destination. Customer said that, he doesn't receive timeouted packets, I don't know where they are lost. Maybe somewhere in Azure?

Comment: then, make sure every variable is defined in your connection string. including port.

Comment: they are. I'm logging them before creating of connection.

Comment: try specifying port as a variable. `server=127.0.0.1;userid=azure;password=XXXX;database=localdb;Port=NNNN
`

Comment: i got logs from mysql server and there is a lot of information like that: _/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log:111111 11:11:11 [Warning] Aborted connection 999 to db: 'xxxxxx' user: 'xxxxx' host:
'111.111.111.111' (Got an error reading communication packets)_

Comment: can you post the full log

Comment: This looks like the issue you're facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860486/mysql-how-to-diagnose-cause-of-warning-aborted-connection-got-timeout-read

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have full logs :( File which I received contains logs like I posted above.